# Android CameraX takePicture does not work from android codelab

Tags: android, android-camera, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I was running this code taken from "Getting Started with CameraX" codelab. When I press button I cant see anything from screen or logcat. After that I tried to add external storage write and read permission but it did not change anything. Source codes:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camerax_codelab_sample">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Camerax_codelab_sample">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Set up the listener for take photo button
        activityMainBinding.cameraCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()




        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        Log.d(TAG, "takePhoto inside")
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {


            override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {

                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }

            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }


        })
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable { // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(activityMainBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try { // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()) mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
}
```

Dependencies are same with codelab. Camera Preview works correctly but takePhoto does not. Has anyone else had this problem? , thank you.

Comment: Could you remove the logcat filter and post the logs you see once you try to take a picture?

Comment: Also, looking at the code, you aren't binding the `ImageCapture` use case. Make sure to bind both the `Preview` and `ImageCapture` use cases.